# What USB client modes does Android support

Tags: android, client, usb

I would like to connect my Android Droid phone (acting as a device), to an embedded GPS module (acting as host), over usb.  I have the ability to tweak the firmware on the GPS module (which uses an ARM 710 processor, and is not Linux based).

I know that the Android SDK does not include APIs to control the USB port.  I am hoping I can connect my GPS host to my android phone using a client mode the phone already supports.  I am having difficulty getting this information.

I would appreciate any suggestions, or links on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to tweak the GPS to act in client mode, as android supports host mode (3.1+)